# Count how many time a value appeared in a column in excel?

Tags: excel, count, vba

Ok, So I have an excel file that have a column that may contain duplicate value like this

**PO NUMBER          PO COUNT**
P100293490                      4
P100293490
P100293490
P100293490
P100293492                  2
P100293492
P100293494                  3
P100293494
P100293494
P100293497                  4
P100293497
P100293497
P100293497
P100293499                  1

I need to count how many times it appeared on the column and place it beside the first occurrence of the word. The **PO NUMBER** is sorted from a to z so the arrangement is nothing to worry about.  i tried everything (Lookup, Match, Countif, IF)
and nothing  seems to work. Please Help? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In B2 and copy down:

```
=IF(A2<>A1,COUNTIF(A:A,A2),"")
```

Comment: wow. you just saved my life. and that was fast :O thank you so much :)